# How to know the device media volume is on mute or very low

Tags: cordova, audio, media, volume

My App is playing sounds with Cordova media plugin and I realized I did hear nothing because the multimedia volume was on mute on my Android device! (Enabling it at the sound's settings screen fixed it)

Nevertheless, this can also happen to the end users. How can the App know the device volume is on mute or very low before playing audio for stating the user the volume is on mute or enabling it automatically?
There is a `media.setVolume(1.0)` method but it does not seem to work, at least in Android.

Answer (score 1):

`media.setVolume(1.0)` is just the volume of the sound.

To get the device volume use https://github.com/Whebcraft/fm.radiant.cordova.utils.volume
     `VolumeUtils.setVolume(value, successCallback, failureCallback)` - sets the volume from 0 to 100.

```
VolumeUtils.getVolume(function successCallback(value){
       alert(value);
       }, failureCallback);
```

- gets the volume from 0 to 100